# Ruby FFI Enum usage - sending integer

Tags: ruby, ffi

In the ffi documentation for Enums(https://github.com/ffi/ffi/wiki/Enums) it mentions that when you create an ffi, for example:

```
# Example using enums

module Week
  extend FFI::Library
  ffi_lib "week"

  enum :day, [:sunday, 1,
              :monday,
              :tuesday,
              :wednesday,
              :thursday,
              :friday,
              :saturday ]

  attach_function :is_work_day, [ :day ], :int
end

# How you would call the function:
Week.is_work_day( :monday )

# This is also allowed, in case you need to use integers:
Week.is_work_day( 2 )
```

The question is: When you send the '2' does that look in the :day enum and find the value of the second entry or does it send the actual '2' value to your function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both calls will send the integer `2` to the function. The first call will resolve the symbol `:monday` to `2`, the second one doesn't need to because the 2 was already given.

Comment: Thanks that answers my question! I wasn't sure if it sent 2 to the function or would send the second entry in the array to the function.  Since that could be anything.